# Как быстро записать в 100 текстовых файлов по 100000 строк?

Tags: python, asyncio

Есть задание сгенерировать строку из нескольких частей, а затем в 100 файлов записать по 100000 таких сгенерированных строк.Функция final_string() и генерирует такую строку. [image: функции записи в файл] Попробовал использовать асинхронность, создаю список тасок, но gather их обрабатывает по очереди, а не параллельно, как должен в моём понимании. В чём я ошибаюсь? Может быть, целесообразнее использовать потоки?

Comment: Да, конечно лучше всего использовать потоки, т.к. они не используют GIL для записи и у вас все прекрасно сработает.

Comment: Файловой асинхронности в Python нет.

Comment: ну есть костыль в виде модуля aiofile для любителей async, только вот все равно все станет в очередь к диску и прирост может быть мизерный